# facing Filter chain halted as :load_order_with_lock rendered or redirected issue in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree

I have included given code

```
= form_for @order, :url => update_checkout_path(:payment), :html => { :id => "checkout_form_payment" } do |form|    
    %li#paypal.list-group-item
    %label
      %input#order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_5{:checked => "checked", :name => "order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]", :type => "radio", :value => "5"}
        Test Paypal
        .logo
          %img{:src => "/assets/icons/icon-paypal.png"}
    %li.list-group-item.codMobile#cashondelivery1
        %label
          %input#order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_216{:name => "order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]", :type => "radio", :value => "216", :checked => 'checked'}
          Cash On Delivery   

    = submit_tag Spree.t(:order_now), :class => 'order-now btn btn-danger'
```

when I click on order now button it gives me following error

Started PATCH "/checkout/update/payment" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-04 11:46:43 +0530

```
Processing by Spree::CheckoutController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9IqXtiQ+KUhFiwbMUFHT2sRSU4Ojpm9/n/e5ghdYeqc=", "order"=>{"payments_attributes"=>[{"payment_method_id"=>"216"}], "cod_pay"=>"true"}, "cardHolder"=>"Dinshaw Raje", "cardNumber"=>"[FILTERED]", "credit"=>"2016", "cardCode"=>"", "commit"=>"Order Now", "payment_source"=>{"16"=>{"encrypted_data"=>"adyenjs_0_1_2$Its/q0yCQWYzLCNc6nWiyrkzw7QJGKBjDNRhgyIIikJygUmPewpVoNCFzSDttFrc7EuiOVv0gojezOghgMdaW3PMuwWXmo97FhAw+NpSiqv0GkxNWRHmUxFNhv1BxkNPkD1Ar9kTy56bmlVcBzS25f6cERIiKuvLzHwlBlh6WYT7oFAhFW4IL4LeIa8FsYxahuFvWBQnqbloc/WtIAkuQrz0HfmGhWK+tMRsUXhJ0sxZSegLQvozR1v1IpfEaA1DLoChADC3u8J7kuBcgfAgRUo0vSNHHm6UM6NqGVNlbWyDHNndh44RGMi4MhKVeO2IZ9Ggwp5/wSnlfGe9Xv8nxA==$V1F0hQhKIV7FyCEjjb9YsV+7C+yuNMo37L9nydKIKHgbknZ75b2lsTS5cRW0l+1B+9eltzOgBm2kmFVqiQeosqStxS1KbnFFFK3ex4cbVKCGZ/e80478RjVxy0lgCG/5B0sr2+/SsdyQG6GBH3NSl9z573pDMhVOGQQmUzLVtoLR/AUjSPGvOtBRDrlV2mDcxeQRWknk1i3Z"}}, "state"=>"payment"}
  Spree::Country Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_countries".* FROM "spree_countries"  WHERE "spree_countries"."name" = 'N/A' LIMIT 1
  Spree::Order Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders"  WHERE "spree_orders"."completed_at" IS NULL AND "spree_orders"."currency" = 'USD' AND "spree_orders"."guest_token" = 'AiRxQFCYCRNMLSXXbwSiGg' AND "spree_orders"."user_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
  Spree::Adjustment Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "spree_adjustments".* FROM "spree_adjustments"  WHERE "spree_adjustments"."adjustable_type" = 'Spree::Order' AND "spree_adjustments"."adjustable_id" IN (6131)  ORDER BY spree_adjustments.created_at ASC
   (2.1ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Order Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders"  WHERE "spree_orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 6131]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/checkout/address
Filter chain halted as :load_order_with_lock rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)
```

When I had run following query in console

> Spree::Order.incomplete.lock(true).find_by(currency:'USD',
>   guest_token: 'AiRxQFCYCRNMLSXXbwSiGg')

```
Spree::Order Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders"  WHERE "spree_orders"."completed_at" IS NULL AND "spree_orders"."currency" = 'USD' AND "spree_orders"."guest_token" = 'AiRxQFCYCRNMLSXXbwSiGg' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
=> #<Spree::Order id: 6131, number: "R681473667", item_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89c42e0,'0.1448E3',18(18)>, total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89c41c8,'0.899E2',18(18)>, state: "address", adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89c4010,'-0.549E2',18(18)>, user_id: nil, completed_at: nil, bill_address_id: 26488, ship_address_id: 26489, payment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89b79c8,'0.0',9(18)>, shipping_method_id: nil, shipment_state: nil, payment_state: nil, email: "test@gmail.com", special_instructions: nil, created_at: "2016-02-04 06:15:13", updated_at: "2016-02-04 06:16:29", currency: "USD", last_ip_address: "127.0.0.1", created_by_id: nil, shipment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89b6370,'0.0',9(18)>, additional_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89b6280,'0.0',9(18)>, promo_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89b6168,'-0.549E2',18(18)>, channel: "spree", included_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7f8fb89b6028,'0.0',9(18)>, item_count: 2, approver_id: nil, approved_at: nil, confirmation_delivered: false, considered_risky: false, guest_token: "AiRxQFCYCRNMLSXXbwSiGg", locale: nil, state_lock_version: 0, cod_pay: false, cod_amount: nil>
```

Please guide where I am wrong. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that there is no matching order in the DB. Since, `@order` is `nil`, you are getting redirected. Verify that the order you are looking for is not yet `complete`. If the `order` is already `complete`, this redirect will happen.

If this doesn't work out, try running the exact query from your console and see if it actually returns any `order`.

You can try running this in console. Please modify the `params` based on your data.

```
Spree::Order.incomplete.lock(true).find_by(currency:'AED', guest_token: 'D2dIKPb9llIco2itPqTl6g', user_id: nil)
```

Comment: My order state is not `complete` but when I had run given query it returns me an order. Please guide me how to overcome with this error @Nerve

Comment: Is the order you are getting the one that you are trying to checkout or is it a different order? Can you paste the result of above query?

Comment: In your original query, the currency was setting as 'AED'. Also, you are not passing `store_id`. AFAIK, Spree::Order object contains `store_id` that seems missing from your object. If this doesn't help, please let me know the spree version you are on.

Comment: I am using `gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-3-stable'
`

Comment: check if you can upgrade to 2-4-stable